# Disable ReSharper inline rename in VS2015

Tags: .net, resharper, visual-studio-2015

How do you disable ReSharper from intercepting F2 for inline rename?

If I reset the keyboard bindings in ReSharper and press alt+enter or ctrl+t it will ask me which shortcut I want to use but this does not happen for F2 and ReSharper just takes over.

Edit: I have raised the following feature request to make this a possibility: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-440809

Comment: Why not simply unbind `F2` from Rename and bind it to the command you need? After all, you cannot run Visual Studio's *Rename*, that command is overridden by R#.

Comment: What is the Visual Studio inline rename function that I can bind to?
F2 is already bound to Refactor.Rename which is what I thought the built in rename function was but that launches ReSharper's rename.

Comment: sorry but I don't think you can use VS's `Refactor.Rename`. R# is configured implicitly to intercept that command.

Comment: I have raised a feature request with ReSharper to allow users to disable this behavior. To be fair this is the first time the IDE has provided such a good refactoring experience all on its own from my memory.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-440809